# Technical Question Ether to BNB transfer

Tags: ether, recovery, transfer

I attempted to swap funds from Ethereum to BNB via the Binance Bridge feature and pancake swap via my Metamask.

I was trying to send the ETH to myself. I did not have any BNB to do the transaction, however the transaction sent in ETH.

I have the eth address that was created by the BSC Bridge but the transaction can only be found on the ETHERSCAN, not the BSC CHAIN.

The transaction was successful but cannot find the ETH any where; I can see the transaction withdrawal in my Metamask, but no deposit in my BSC.

I'm completely lost as to how to retrieve the funds. I can see where they have gone (supposedly me) but I cannot see the funds in Metamask.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Did it work? If not, please let us know the address to take a look at the issue.